# Integrating Blazor Server-side with WASM

Tags: iis, blazor, webassembly

Most of my homepage is very SQL-intensive and has CPU-intensive tasks (processing audio etc.), and I've chosen to make it all Server-side.

But there are SOME things I'd like to make pure WASM.  For example, I have some image editing that would benefit from faster interactivity-- rotating and sizing images in real time and so on.

How should I integrate both paradigms?  I'm considering the following options so far:
-just treat them as separate apps, and configure navigation in IIS
-embed the WASM in the main page using an iFrame (is this even possible)?
-???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use both Blazor client and server in same web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131674/how-to-use-both-blazor-client-and-server-in-same-web)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to mix client side and server side methods in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59654438/11683)

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for your input.  Those are good links, and I watched the video with great interest.  But other than talk of throwing WASM files in the wwwroot folder, I didn't actually see a method that I could apply.  A LOT has happened since those questions were asked, so I'm curious if new developments change things.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 If you want to connect your wasm to your SQL server look at this : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0Tj0VIUCtA  ODATA query's if done right will go straight through to the SQL server. No data filtering, sorting or paging in the server app.

Comment: .NET 6 is crazy.  In 30 years of programming, I've never seen one company or framework get so much right in such a short timespan.  With Blazor and Unity, my programming universe has absolutely exploded!  /fanboyrant

Comment: That being said, my site is currently near the end of its development cycle-- about 5,000-10,000 lines of code I'd guess?  So I'm really looking to fit a few WASM components into what I'm working with already.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - See this Repo of mine on combining WASM and Server - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/AllinOne.  It might give you some pointers.  There's also another Repo on there called Hydra which shows how you can run multiple Server and WASM SPAs under one roof.

Comment: Okay, that sounds very promising.  I'll check it out for sure!